# Portability of dlfunc?

Tags: c, dlopen

I'm reading through the manpage for dlopen and friends on FreeBSD. I'm working on a cross-platform application that is using shared libraries for loadable plugins. I've never done this before, but I think I have a decent grasp of how it works. The manpage mentions dlsym(), which appears to be the common means of getting a function pointer from a shared library, and dlfunc(), which supposedly avoids compiler complaints about casting a void* to a function pointer. Is there a reason dlsym() is more common (portability?) ? I'm wondering whether I should use dlfunc() to avoid compiler problems, or use dlsym(). Is dlfunc() portable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't expect to have a `dlfunc` provided on other UNIXes, but it's implementation is straightforward and portable.  You can do something like

```
# configure.ac
AC_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([dlfunc])

// some common header
#include "config.h"
#ifndef HAVE_DLFUNC
/* copied from FreeBSD, source/include/dlfcn.h */
struct __dlfunc_arg {
        int __dlfunc_dummy;
};
typedef void (*dlfunc_t)(struct __dlfunc_arg);
dlfunc_t dlfunc(void *restrict handle, void *restrict symbol);
#endif

// some source file
#include "config.h"
#ifndef HAVE_DLFUNC
/* copied from FreeBSD, lib/libc/gen/dlfunc.c */
dlfunc_t dlfunc(void *restrict handle, void *restrict symbol) {
        union {
                void *d;
                dlfunc_t f;
        } rv;
        rv.d = dlsym(handle, symbol);
        return rv.f;
}
#endif
```

if you are using Autoconf, and other build+configuration systems probably have similar abilities.  (`dlsym` is much more widely available.)

---

That being said, I think the compiler warning is silly – the C standard does not, but POSIX guarantees that `void *` pointers can safely represent all function pointers…

Answer (score 1):

When you say cross platform, do you mean cross-POSIX platforms or do you need Windows support too?

If you're working in C++ you could have a look at the [Boost.Extension proposal code](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/browser/sandbox/libs/extension/). This takes care of Windows vs. UNIX portability.

If you're looking for UNIX-only advice, have a look at the [Single UNIX Specification](http://www.unix.org/single_unix_specification/).

As far as I know, dlsym is the standard UNIX way to do things. Windows has an equivalent but completely different way of doing things.

Comment: Cross-platform in this case is cross-POSIX. I have very little desire to begin digging into the dark depths of Windows programming.

Comment: HP-UX - at least on PA-RISC machines (getting towards archaic, I know) has a separate system.  I think the IA64 machines use dlsym()/dlopen().

Comment: Yep, 32 bit HP-UX on PA-RISC uses the SOM format (shlib_* functions), which is a bit nasty (and apparently doesn't do reference counting). 64 bit HP-UX on PA-RISC uses ELF, as do both 32 and 64 bit HP-UX on ia64 - these have the more sane dl* interfaces.